# softlink to binary always use home folder path (instead of current folder)

Tags: linux, bash, symlink, appimage

kdevelop provides this [AppImage](https://www.kdevelop.org/download) binary:

```
wget -O KDevelop.AppImage https://download.kde.org/stable/kdevelop/5.1.1/bin/linux/KDevelop-5.1.1-x86_64.AppImage
chmod +x KDevelop.AppImage
./KDevelop.AppImage
```

It works well. So I want to make a soft link called `kd` to that binary in `/usr/bin`, eg:

```
/usr/bin/sudo ln -s KDevelop-5.1.1-x86_64.AppImage kd
```

Now if I run `kd file1`, I'd expect that it would open a file name `file1` in the **current** folder, but it always tries to open a file name `file1` in my **home** folder - which is not where it should be.

Is there some way to fix this issue?

Comment: May be, the appl. behaves different if not called with its original binary name. Did you try to use `alias kd=KDevelop-5.1.1-x86_64.AppImage` instead of `ln -s`?

Comment: Perhaps a function called kd can help.

Comment: @Scheff thanks, I tried `alias kdd='/usr/bin/KDevelop-5.1.1-x86_64.AppImage'` but same issue with alias `kdd` - it always open file in home folder.

Comment: The function trick of @Cyrus could be combined with e.g. `"$PWD/$1"` to prefix the file name with the current directory.

Comment: @Scheff I actually used that "`pwd`/file1" - it worked, just not quite sure whether this is an _expected_ behavior or some buggy stuff; I don't recall having to prefix `pwd` with any other application I used before ;)

Answer (score 1):

Some possible causes:

- The application always assumes that you want to open files in your home directory, effectively or literally prepending `$HOME` to the path. This would be a *bug* in any *nix program, and should be reported.
- The application behaves differently when `$(basename "$0")` is not `KDevelop.AppImage` (what [@Scheff said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44993608/softlink-to-binary-always-use-home-folder-path-instead-of-current-folder#comment76961999_44993608)).
- You are actually running a *different* `kd`.

Possible workarounds/investigations:

- Pass the full path to the file on the command line. If it tries to open /home/you//full/path/you/provided it is obviously buggy, and you have a test case. If it does not, then there might be some gotcha to what your `$PWD` actually is. Try checking its value before running.
- Symlink with the same name, using `sudo ln -s KDevelop-5.1.1-x86_64.AppImage /usr/bin`, and try running that. If it behaves the same, you've at least proven that the symlink is not the problem.
- Run `type -a kd` and verify that your /usr/bin/kd comes up first. If not there might be an alias or shell built-in which takes precedence.

That said, what is the actual error message?

Comment: thanks, I tried `alias kdd='/usr/bin/KDevelop-5.1.1-x86_64.AppImage'` but same issue with alias `kdd` - it always open file in home folder.

There was actually no error message, it's just that kdevelop keeps assuming file in _home_ folder instead of _current_ folder where the command is issued

Comment: I agree this might be a bug with kdevelop AppImage; could not see any problems with symlinks etc. see self answer